# Estoy cargando fotos desde FireBase a mi RecyclerView y las fotos se ven cortadas como esta en la imagen

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-glide

**Estes es mi Adaptador**

```
    public class Myadaptador extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadaptador.ViewHolder> {


    private static Bitmap bitmap_transfer;

    public static Bitmap getBitmap_transfer() {
        return bitmap_transfer;
    }



    public static void setBitmap_transfer(Bitmap bitmap_transfer_param) {
        bitmap_transfer = bitmap_transfer_param;
    }


    private Context context;

    private List<Upload> subidas;


    Activity activity = (Activity) context;


    public Myadaptador(Context context, List<Upload> subidas) {

        this.subidas = subidas;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_images, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final Upload upload = subidas.get(position);



        Glide.with(context)
                .load(upload.getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        

        holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //Comparto Texto con otras Apps
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hola");
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(shareIntent);


            }
        });




    }

    @Override
     public int getItemCount() {

    return subidas.size();
}

 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

     public TextView textViewName;
     public ImageView imageView;
     public TextView share;



     public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
         super(itemView);


         imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
         share = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.compartir);



         imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {


                 imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                 setBitmap_transfer(imageView.getDrawingCache());

                 Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Touchedimagen.class);
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                 context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);


                 //Mostrar una transicion(ANIMACION) al cambiar de actividad
                 ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.scale_down);


             }
         });


     }

    }
 }
```

**Este es mi Layout**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/fondo"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blanco" />



       </LinearLayout>
```

**Imagen cortada**

[image: Imagen cortada]

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo manejas desde el imageView con la propiedad android:scaleType

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoBack"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cirle_background" />
```

Aca te paso que hace cada opción:

[image: Scale Types]

Comment: gracias crack por detenerte a responder. 

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido, te mando un saludo!